# What are some good resource to learn chess notation?

Tags: notation, recommendations

I want to learn Chess systematically from the beginning. Although, I have 700+ Elo on chess.com but I think, it is just a random play: sometimes luck and sometimes 4 moves checkmate (Bishop and Queen) helps or sometimes opponent is naïve than me or opponent resigns without playing and I get points.

Recently, I was reading Pawn Structure Chess by Andrew Soltis (and then planning to read Jeremy Silman - How to Reassess Your Chess) as I thought pawns are important part and their movement should be done with conscious choice and not treat them as useless chess pieces.

But I can't understand all notation while following Andrew Soltis' book:

I  e4 e5
2 Nf3 Nc6 -> What does N mean?
3 Bb5 a6
4 Ba4 Nf6
5  o..o Be7 -> what is o..o?
6 Rel   b5
7  Bb3   d6
8 c3   o..o
9 h3   Bb7
10 d4  Re8
11 Nbd2  Bf8
12  a4 h6
13  Bc2  exd4 what is x in exd4?
14 cxd4  Nb4
15 Bbl  bxa4
16 Rxa4  a5
17 Ra3 Ra6 what is a in Ra3 and Ra6?
18 Nh2 g6

Comment: if you search on youtube you will get a bunch of videos. If there is any youtuber you prefer watching chances are they will have a video on this topic

Comment: N stands for "kNight". 0-0 is short castling. The Wikipedia article on algebraic notation should be good enough I think. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_notation_(chess)

Comment: N means Knight. 0-0 short castling, 0-0-0 long castling. x means capture, + means check, ++ double check, # means mate, ! - brilliant move, ? - mistake, ?! - dubious move, !? - interesting move, +- White is winning, -+ Black is winning, ± White stands better, ∓ Black stands better, ⩲ White is very slightly better, ⩱ Black is very slightly better. Pawns structures, specific openings, etc. are not the best topic for beginners.  There was a question posted here about beginner needing to study openings - it should help you. Books for beginners/casual players explain terminology and notation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could start just with the wikipedia page here for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_notation_(chess)

Also there were (at least - could be more) two lessons on the notation on chess.com as you mentioned that page. One is in the guide in the section "Playing the game" and called "The language of chess". Then there is in the section "Reading the board" the course "Advanced Chess notation".

Answer (score 5):

> Which is the best resource to learn chess notation?

The best resource which is also free is Appendix C of the [FIDE Laws of Chess](https://old.fide.com/fide/handbook.html?id=208&view=article).

Comment: Good resource but maybe a little formal for a beginner.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a short and interactive [tutorial](https://odinchess.com/tutorials/PGN-Tutorial). It covers the basics and shows a few examples. I am the author of the tutorial.